# Significant location not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11

I develop my app with iOS 10.3 and using significant location, its working fine. But when I build my app in iOS 11, significant location is not working and didn't get call in Location manager "didUpdate location" method.

Answer (score 1):

For **iOS 11**, you have to add the key `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `Info.plist`.